# Am I running the right SQL query?

Tags: sql

I have the following tables,

Listing:

```
ID varchar2(33)
Name varchar2(100)
```

Users:

```
ID varchar2(33)
Name varchar2(100)
```

User_Listing

```
ID auto-generated
UserId references ID from Users
ListingId references ID from Listing
```

I want to find the favorite listing of users (in this case the listing with highest count in the User_listing table. For e.g.
if the user_listing table contains`<id,user_id,listing_id>,`

```
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 2 3
1 3 3
```

The favorite listing is 3

Is this the right query to run ?

```
Select Listing.name
  from Listing
 where Listing.id = (Select p.id 
                       from User_listing p, User_listing q
                     having count(p.id) > count(q.id)
                      GROUP BY p.id)
```

Also, if I had to print out the top 5 favorites, how can i do that ?

Comment: For the second question use **LIMIT** to select first five records

Comment: Adding a tag with the corresponding RDBMS you are using will help to get you better answers. As You see, the answerers are trying to give you an answer on all the RDBMS, and that is not necessary, unless you ask for it directly.

Comment: There is no JOIN in the sub-select. That looks suspicous.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what flavor of SQL you're using, at least for the part where you get the top 5 records. In SQL Server, you will use "Select Top 5". In MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, etc., it's "Limit 5".

Here's a MySQL solution that selects all information about the top 5 listings:

```
SELECT * FROM listing
JOIN 
(SELECT listing_id
FROM user_listing
GROUP BY listing_id 
ORDER BY count(listing_id) DESC
LIMIT 5) as top_five ON top_five.listing_id=listing.id;
```

If you just need the ids of the top listings, you can do it like this instead:

```
SELECT listing_id
    FROM user_listing
    GROUP BY listing_id 
    ORDER BY count(listing_id) DESC
    LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle way

```
select * from (
    select ListingID, Name, count(*) FrequencyOfListingID
      from UserListing, Listing
     where Listing.ID = UserListing.ListingID
     group by ListingID 
     order by 2 desc) 
 where rownum < 6
```

MsSql way **not tested**

```
    select Top 5 ListingID, Name, count(*) FrequencyOfListingID
      from UserListing, Listing
     where Listing.ID = UserListing.ListingID
     group by ListingID 
     order by 2 desc)
```

MySQl way **not tested**

```
    select ListingID, Name, count(*) FrequencyOfListingID
      from UserListing, Listing
     where Listing.ID = UserListing.ListingID
     group by ListingID 
     order by 2 desc 
     Limit 5
```